# How to load item text to javascript?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-apex, vis.js

I generate the JSON nodes and edges for the vis.js library and hold them into an item.

So for example:

```
 var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
  { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
  { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
  { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
  { id: 5, label: "Node 5" },
  { id: 6, label: "Node 6" },
  { id: 7, label: "Node 7" },
  { id: 8, label: "Node 8" },
]);
```

I want to replace the JSON above with the item value I tried with:
`$v("PXX_JSON");` and  `JSON.parse($v("PXX_JSON"));` but it doesn't work.

Update: I already have JSON stored in item, I just want to get the item value in js code.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I misunderstand your question but as I understand, you have a JSON as above and you want to hold that value in a page item right?
If you do, use `$s('Pxx_ITEM')` for setting the value then parse the value with `JSON.parse($v("Pxx_ITEM"));`.

Comment: I alredy have json stored in an item, I just want to get the item text(json) in js code.